Do we need to save OAuth2AuthorizationRequest in OAuth2AuthorizationService.save method?
I am using Spring Authorization Server to create an authorization server.
For saving and retrieving authorizations, I have implemented a custom authorization service implementing the OAuth2AuthorizationService interface. When the save method is invoked, I save the client, grant type, authorized scopes, principal and the tokens available in the authorization object. I do not save any attributes of the authorization object as I have not defined any custom attributes.
When I send the request to /authorize endpoint, I get beack the authorization code and it is saved to the DB as expected. However, when I invoke the /token endpoint to get the access token, an exception is thrown.
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.endpoint.OAuth2AuthorizationRequest.getAdditionalParameters()" because

"authorizationRequest" is null at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.authentication.CodeVerifierAuthenticator.authenticate(CodeVerifierAuthenticator.java:97) at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.authentication.CodeVerifierAuthenticator.authenticatelfAvailable(CodeVerifierAuthenticator.java:73) at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.authentication.ClientSecretAuthentication Provider.authenticate(ClientSecretAuthenticationProvider.java:151) at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:182) at org.springframework.security.authentication. ObservationAuthenticationManager.lambda$authenticate$1(ObservationAuthenticationManager.java:54)

I traced the null OAuth2AuthorizationRequest object to CodeVerifierAuthenticator.authenticate method:
OAuth2AuthorizationRequest authorizationRequest = (OAuth2AuthorizationRequest)authorization.getAttribute(OAuth2AuthorizationRequest.class.getName()); 


Since, I am not saving the authorization request present as attribute in authorization object, I cannot fetch it back. Also, I do not think that the authorization request itself would need to be stored.
Therefore, I want to confirm if it indeed needs to be saved or maybe I am doing something wrong.
I have tried to create a new authorization request object and assigning it to authorization after fetching it from DB. However, the Authorization request builder is only available for Authorization grant type and required request URI which I don't want to hardcode.

First of all, let talk about the flow /token you are using. In here Spring oauth2 server, we can see that Spring support these grant-type The supported authorization grant types are authorization_code, refresh_token, client_credentials, urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:device_code, and urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:token-exchange.
I believe that you had used authorization_code (which will need authorization first before get token), this grant_type is use for normal flow (send oauth2/authorize request then /oauth2/token). In case you only want token without needing oauth2/authorization request, use the client_credentials grant_type, which will need client_id, client-secret in base64.
In your question, do we need to have authorization? Yes and no, somehow Spring support with many grant_type, customable method and those will look for authorization as default. Change this logic will lead you to change all the library of Spring. But in the other hand, if you dont want to care much about this, leave it and Spring will you it in memory automatically.


For saving and retrieving authorizations, I have implemented a custom authorization service implementing the OAuth2AuthorizationService interface.

Please take a look at the guide How-to: Implement core services with JPA for a guide on implementing your own services. Notice that it does indeed store attributes. You will also need to do this because it is required by the framework. When following the guide, you can plug in your own persistence instead of using JPA.
